# How can I access a Form's textbox from an instance of a class?

Tags: c#

Inside my `public partial class frmMain : Form` I have `private class Tile`.

Inside the class `Tile` I have `private PictureBox pic = new PictureBox();`.

I have registered a click event for those pictureBoxes (inside the `Tile` class):

```
public void Initialize()
{
    pic.Click += new EventHandler(swap);
}
```

When I click a pictureBox I want to be able to see textbox1.Text.

```
private void swap(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // code here //
    if (won)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text);
    }
}
```

How can I make `textbox1.Text` and some other fields of my frmMain instance visible?

Comment: Did you change the modifier to public for the textBox1 control? Also, do you have a static instance of frmMain or singleton frmMain? Doing that should work.

Comment: Currently if you put `MessageBox.Show("some message");` in swap method, does it display the message box with message "some message"?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya yes.

Comment: @Nathangrad neither works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest solution would be to pass frmMain as parameter to Tile class. Tile class would be:

```
private class Tile {
     private frmMain frm;
     //constructor
     public Tile(frmMain frm) {
          this.frm = frm;
     }
     ... your code ... 
     //now you can
     private void swap(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
          if (won)
          {
               MessageBox.Show(frm.textBox1.Text);
          }
     }
}
```

Remember that the textBox1 have to be public accessible from frmMain.

The cleanest solution would be to expose interface from frmMain and pass it as parameter to Tile class.

Interface

```
public interface IfrmMain_GetText
{
    string gettextBox1Text();
}
```

frmMain

```
public partial class frmMain : Form, IfrmMain_GetText
{
      ... your code ...
      public string gettextBox1Text(){
           return textBox1.Text;
      }
}
```

Tile class

```
private class Tile {
         private IfrmMain_GetText frmInterface;
         //constructor
         public Tile(IfrmMain_GetText frmInterface) {
              this.frmInterface = frmInterface;
         }
         ... your code ... 
         //now you can
         private void swap(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
              if (won)
              {
                   MessageBox.Show(frmInterface.gettextBox1Text());
              }
         }
    }
```

Comment: Just call from frmMain:  Tile yourName = new Tile(this); And set textBox1 public as  CodingYoshi proposed.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make textbox1.Text and some other fields of my frmMain instance visible?

In C# windows forms, controls are `private` by default. To change the access modifier, you can change it like below:

**Right click the control > Properties > Change dropdown as shown below**

[image]

I would change it to `internal`, no need to make it public in your case.

That means classes outside the class where the control is (frmMain) can access the control. But your inner class will need a reference to `frmMain` so it can access the controls of `frmMain`. To do that, you can do it in the following ways:

**Option 1**

You can pass the `frmMain` reference to a class in the constructor:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private frmMain someForm;
    public SomeClass(frmMain someForm)
    {
        this.frmMain = someForm;
        // Now you can do this
        var ctrl = this.frmMain.WhateverControlYouNeedToAccess;
        string controlText = ctrl.Text; //assuming it has Text property
    }
}
```

During creation of the `SomeClass`, pass your form to it:

```
// this reference to the current instance
// this code will be in your form
SomeClass some = new SomeClass(this);
```

**Option 2**

In your class have a property so it is settable from outside like this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public frmMain SomeForm { get; set; }
}
```

You will set the property like this:

```
SomeClass some = new SomeClass(); 
some.SomeForm = this;
```

**Option 3**

Only give the class the minimum it needs. You do not need to give it a reference to the whole form but only one control (or more), then pass the control specifically like this:

```
SomeClass some = new SomeClass();
some.PictureBoxA = this.pictureBox1;
some.Button1 = this.button1;
```

For this to work, your class needs to have the properties for the above. So your class will have properties like this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public PictureBox PictureBoxA { get; set; }
    public Button Button1 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It's still not visible, even if I set the property as public.

Comment: @Achilles see my full answer. I had an answer you will need more explanation so I elaborated further.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a form-reference to the nested class. You can do so through constructor.

```
private class Tile
{
    private frmMain _frm;

    public Tile (frmMain frm)
    {
        _frm = frm;
    }

    private void swap(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (won) {
            MessageBox.Show(_frm.textBox1.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

You either need to make `textBox1` public or to encapsulate it in a public property.

---

A cleaner way is to hold the information in a data class and to use object binding to bind its properties to the textboxes. Then you can pass this data object to the `Tile` class.

See: [A Detailed Data Binding Tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24656/A-Detailed-Data-Binding-Tutorial) on CodeProject.

I don't know what kind of data is displayed on your form, but if tile data is displayed, then the `Tile` class could act as data class and you could bind the tile object to your form.